# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids' in Kivy when Clock.schedule_interval function is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, attributeerror

I am facing an Attribute error in the code below. I am new to this kivy framework. When I tried to call the Clock.schedule_interval function to infinite scroll the image. *Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.ids.mainwindow.scroll_textures, 1/60.)*
*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'*
This error popped up.
The .py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.config import Config

# You can create your kv code in the Python file

# Create a class for all screens in which you can include
# helpful methods specific to that screen
kv = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class MainWindow(Screen):
    cloud_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    floor_texture = ObjectProperty(None)
    sound = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cloud_texture = Image(source = "cloud4.png").texture
        self.cloud_texture.wrap = 'repeat'
        self.cloud_texture.uvsize = (Window.width/self.cloud_texture.width,-1)
        self.floor_texture = Image(source = "floor2.jpg").texture
        self.floor_texture.wrap = 'repeat'
        self.floor_texture.uvsize = (Window.width/self.floor_texture.width,-1)
        self.sun_texture = Image(source = "sun.png").texture
        self.sun_texture.uvsize = (Window.width/self.sun_texture.width,-1)
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('8bitmenu.wav')
        self.sound.play()

    def scroll_textures(self, time_passed):
        #Update the uvpos
        self.cloud_texture.uvpos = ((self.cloud_texture.uvpos[0] - time_passed/20) % Window.width, self.cloud_texture.uvpos[1])
        self.floor_texture.uvpos = ((self.floor_texture.uvpos[0] + time_passed/8) % Window.width, self.floor_texture.uvpos[1])
        #Redraw textures
        texture = self.property('cloud_texture')
        texture.dispatch(self)

        texture = self.property('floor_texture')
        texture.dispatch(self)

class Window1(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


#Config.write()
class MyApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.root.ids.mainwindow.scroll_textures, 1/60.)
        pass
    def build(self):
        return kv


MyApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
<WindowManager>:
    MainWindow:
    Window1:


<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    id: mainwindow
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            source: "sky.jpg"
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width - 1000, 120
            pos: self.pos[0] + 500, self.pos[1] + self.height - 138
            texture: self.sun_texture
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width, 138
            pos: self.pos[0], self.pos[1] + self.height - 168
            texture: self.cloud_texture
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width, 100
            pos: self.pos[0], self.pos[1]
            texture: self.floor_texture

    Image:
        source: 'dog2.gif'
        anim_delay: 0.09
        size: self.width, self.height
        pos: -270, -270

    Image:
        source: 'boy1.gif'
        anim_delay: 0.09
        size: self.width, self.height
        pos: -100, -230

    Button:
        text: "Start your journey"
        color: .8,.9,0,1
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.3
        halign: 'center'
        center: root.center
        font_size: 12
        size: 32, 32
        size_hint: .2, .2
        pos: 300, 250
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "win1"



<Window1>:
    name: "win1"
    Button:
        text: "Go back"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the Error here. Just declared the id in parent class and that worked

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
        id: mainwindow
    Window1:
```